# Background subtraction + MOOSE filter

Tags: opencv, image-processing, background-subtraction

I'm trying to create a camera with a raspberry pi to detect people moving in a corridor(here I'm assuming only things moving will be people) , and identify the ones who are spending too much time in the area (with the use of a timer) , I use background subtraction to detect the movement and trying to use correlation based tracker such as MOSSE filter to track them. **My question is how to create a bounding box around the moving person after performing background subtraction and pass it to the tracking algorithm to be tracked?**

Answer (score 1):

Background subtraction will return a binary image that contains black and white pixels. By detecting the center of the white contour you can draw a rectangle around the center. The width and height will depend on the contour size.

There are a lot of algorithms, but [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS_uQGOQIdg&list=PLvwB65U8V0HHCEyW2UTyOJym5FsdqfbHQ&index=6) can provide you with a function to get the center of the contour and draw whatever you like around of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blob detection to create bounding box around the detected white pixels. Check this tutorial link:

https://learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/